# When to use a traditional loops over array helpers

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I write in Javascript and I've gotten pretty accustomed to using array helpers as many blogs I've read told me to stay away from for loops entirely if possible.  But there have been a few cases where I need to iterate and the array helpers are less intuitive and more cumbersome than the for loop.  Can you give me a list of situations when you choose to use a traditional loop over an array helper?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example(s) to explain what you are saying?

Comment: The two can't be compared directly because they are not functionally equivalent. Array helpers work only on Arrays. `for` loops can work on any iterable.

Comment: Usually you fall back to recursion in this cases.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Array helpers are intentionally generic; they do not require that the *this* value is an *Array* object. The can be used on other objects that have a length.property and numeric properties for data.

Answer (score 0):

**Breaking out of Loop**

You can't break out of array helpers. So if you need to break out of the loop, you need to use traditional loops.

**Using `yield/await` Inside**

Since you can't pass a `generator` or `async` function as loop `callback`, you need to use traditional loops for it.

Comment: You can easily create your own map/reduce with break semantics or use recursion. However, you're right with `yield`/`await`. That's why why generators/async functions suck (among other things).

Comment: @ftor Yes you can create map/reduce, but I find a `for...of` more convenient unless I'm strictly adhering to functional programming.

Comment: "can't break out of array helpers". Have your heard about [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)?

Answer (score 0):

1. If i needed to break out of the iteration then i would choose to use
   a traditional loop.
   This is because there's no built in ability for `break` using an array helper.
2. If i was writing code that needed to be of the highest performance and readability wasn't a big issue, then I'd go with a traditional loop. I believe a traditional loop is usually quicker than using array helpers (very slightly)

Comment: On second point, you don't need jquery alternatives, javascript has builtin array helpers namely, `forEach/map/filter/reduce`. Performance difference should be marginal.

Comment: OK, ill rephrase this to array helpers in a whole. As I still believe a `for` has a slightly better performance than `forEach`.. depending on the circumstances

Answer (score 0):

**Use whatever makes your code more readable.** (as long as you don't use *for..in*)

You can use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)).
There are differences in how they handle sparce arrays and non numeric enumerable properties.

- Do you need to know the index of the element in the array?
- How do you want to handle undefined elements?
- Do you want to process all elements or do you want to break on some condition?
- If using *for..in*, are you prepared to handle enumerable properties that are not numeric, defined on Array.prototype or Object.prototype? (see below)
- What is easier for a human to read and understand?

You can test the functions below. The array is sparce, and I added both numeric and non-numeric properties on Object.prototype, Array.prototype and on the local array, to show what happens.

```
Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
  globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false },
  globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true },
  "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false },
  "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true }
});

Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
  globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false },
  globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true },
  "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false },
  "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true }
});

const data = ["A", "B", "C"];

data[23] = "X";
data[24] = "Y";
data[25] = "Z";

Object.defineProperties(data, {
  localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false },
  localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true }
});
```

**for** 26 iterations, sparce arrays vulnerable to numeric properties anywhere in the chain

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) console.log(i, data[i]);
```

**for..in**
11 iterations, vulnerable to all enumerable properties anywhere in the chain

Note that *for..in* includes enumerable properties defined anywhere in the prototype chain. It can be on the *local array*, *Array.prototype* or *Object.prototype*.

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

for (const index in data) console.log(index, data[index]);
```

**forEach**
10 iterations, sparce arrays vulnerable to numeric properties anywhere in the prototype chain.

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

data.forEach((value, index) => console.log(index, value));
```

**for..of**
26 iterations, no index, sparce arrays vulnerable to numeric properties anywhere in the chain

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

console.log("for..of, 26 iterations, no index, space arrays vulrenable to numeric properties on Array and Object");
for (const value of data) console.log(value);
```

**for..of Object.entries()** 7 iterations, includes enumerable properties on the local array.

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

for (const [index, value] of Object.entries(data)) console.log(index, value);
```

**some** 9 iterations, sparce arrays vulnerable to numeric properties anywhere in the chain

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

data.some((value, index) => {
  console.log(value, index);
  return value === "Y"; // Exit loop if value is "Y"
});
```

**every** 9 iterations,sparce arrays vulnerable to numeric properties anywhere in the chain

```js
const data = ["A", "B", "C"]; data[23] = "X"; data[24] = "Y"; data[25] = "Z"; Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, { globalObjectUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalObjectEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "10": { value: "Missuse on Object, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "11": { value: "Missuse on Object, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, { globalArrayUnenumerableProperty: { value: "might be ok", enumerable: false }, globalArrayEnumerableProperty: { value: "breaks arrays for everyone", enumerable: true }, "12": { value: "Missuse on Array, non-enumerable", enumerable: false }, "13": { value: "Missuse on Array, enumerable", enumerable: true } }); Object.defineProperties(data, { localUnenumerableProperty: { value: "localUnenumerable", enumerable: false }, localEnumerableProperty: { value: "localMissuseOfArray", enumerable: true } });

data.every((value, index) => {
  console.log(value, index);
  return value !== "Y"; // Exit loop if value is "Y"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me tell you by using some use cases 
1. Using classic or traditional for loop over array helpers functions depends upon the use cases

Let me compare classic for loop which forEach helper 
1. ForEach - less code , minimum risk for syntax error , in for loop we can have logical or syntax error like when providing the condition. 
2. Fetch - When iterating over the data . If data is less then classic for loop will take less time and if more then it may take long time .